# Erase multiple elements in deque C++

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, deque

I was trying to erase multiple elements in deque in the 'while' loop below, but my program does not give the correct results.

## Problem Background:

`packet_deque` contains 9 `Packet` objects - some of them are sent and the others are not sent.

```
#include <deque> 
#include <iostream> 

class Packet
{
public:
    void set_sent() { sent = true; };
    bool get_sent() { return sent; };
private:
    /* members of Test class */
    bool sent = false;
};

int main()
{ 
    size_t MAX = 9;
    std::deque<Packet> packet_deque(MAX);
    unsigned int i = 0;

    std::deque<Packet>::iterator itr = packet_deque.begin();
    printf("Before erasing sent packets - packet_dequeue size: %d \n", packet_deque.size());
    // initialise the packet queue - creating some sent packets
    for (; itr != packet_deque.end(); ++itr) 
    {
        // set some sent packets
        if (i % 3 == 0) 
        {
            itr->set_sent();
        }
        printf("packet_deque[%d]: %s\n", i, itr->get_sent() ? "sent" : "not_sent");
        ++i;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // erase sent packets in packet_dequeue
    itr = packet_deque.begin();
    while (itr != packet_deque.end())
    {
        if (itr->get_sent())
        {
            // erase the element and do NOT move the pointer
            packet_deque.erase(itr);
        }
        else
        {
            // move to next element
            ++itr;
        }
    }

    printf("After erasing sent packets - packet_dequeue size: %d \n", packet_deque.size());
    for (itr = packet_deque.begin(), i = 0; itr != packet_deque.end(); ++itr) 
    {
        printf("packet_deque[%d]: %s\n", i, itr->get_sent() ? "sent" : "not_sent");
        ++i;
    }
}
```

The terminal output is:

```
Before erasing sent packets - packet_dequeue size: 9 
packet_deque[0]: sent
packet_deque[1]: not_sent
packet_deque[2]: not_sent
packet_deque[3]: sent
packet_deque[4]: not_sent
packet_deque[5]: not_sent
packet_deque[6]: sent
packet_deque[7]: not_sent
packet_deque[8]: not_sent

After erasing sent packets - packet_dequeue size: 5 
packet_deque[0]: not_sent
packet_deque[1]: not_sent
packet_deque[2]: not_sent
packet_deque[3]: not_sent
packet_deque[4]: not_sent
```

## Question:

Since the `while` loop just removes `sent` packets, I expect 6 unsent packets, but only got 5.
I couldn't figure out what went wrong... 
Why the final result only contains 5 unsent packets instead of 6 unsent packets?

Comment: Use the `erase / remove_if` idiom.  There is no need to write a loop.

Comment: `itr = packet_deque.erase(itr);`

Comment: Once you remove an element, the iterator is no longer valid.

Comment: The usual approach would be `erase(remove(...` /  `erase(remove_if(...`..

Comment: @zdf Luckily [std::deque::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase) returns you a *new* iterator.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I missed that.

Comment: `packet_deque.erase(std::remove_if(packet_deque.begin(), packet_deque.end(), [](Packet& p) { return p.get_sent(); }), packet_deque.end());`  -- No loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah. That's how I'd write it as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general all iterators are invalidated after an erase from a deque. Your code uses the invalidated iterator in the while condition.

However `erase` returns a new valid iterator pointing to the element immediately after the erased one, so the correct code is

```
itr = packet_deque.erase(itr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
itr = packet_deque.erase(itr);
```

Otherwise the current iterator is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase)

> All iterators and references are invalidated, unless the erased elements are at the end or the beginning of the container, in which case only the iterators and references to the erased elements are invalidated.

So your loop

```cpp
    while (itr != packet_deque.end())
    {
        if (itr->get_sent())
        {
            // erase the element and do NOT move the pointer
            packet_deque.erase(itr);
        }
        else
        {
            // move to next element
            ++itr;
        }
    }
```

is effectively wrong.

Edit: you should use `itr = packet_deque.erase(itr);` to get a valid iterator.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really provide OP with a solution. You are just pointing out that the posted code is wrong. You should improve your answer by showing a *correct* solution.